# How to Fetch data from Array in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_id] => 23233
            [post_id] => 4467
            [meta_key] => first_name
            [meta_value] => Daud
        )

)
```

How can I echo post_id from this array for all posts using while or foreach statement?

```
    Array
(
    [classic-editor-remember] => Array
        (
            [0] => classic-editor
        )

    [_edit_lock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1582905950:5
        )

    [_edit_last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

    [_thumbnail_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4376
        )

    [slide_template] => Array
        (
            [0] => default
        )

    [_yoast_wpseo_content_score] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
        )

    [_yoast_wpseo_primary_advisor_category] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Demo Daniel Wrenne, CFP, ChFC
        )

    [designation] => Array
        (
            [0] => Wrenne Financial Planing, LLC Lexington, KY
        )

    [client_specialities] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gen Y/Millennials, Medical Professionals
        )

    [address] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3223 S LEHI DR
        )

    [phone_number] => Array
        (
            [0] => 64646446486
        )

    [email_address] => Array
        (
            [0] => demo@demo.com
        )

    [website_url] => Array
        (
            [0] => a:3:{s:3:"url";s:23:"https://www.google.com/";s:4:"text";s:20:"View Advisor Profile";s:6:"target";s:4:"none";}
        )

    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Daud
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Yahya
        )

)
```

---

And how can I get las_name, first_name, email, address, website url, specialities, designation and title from the above array using and loop like while or foreach loop.

Comment: Please improve your question, its not possible to understand what you want

Comment: FYI, pulling all the meta data like that might cause the website to slow down when the amount of meta data increases. You should thing about using `get_post_meta()` with the particular keys instead of doing it like this

Answer (score 0):

This is less a WordPress question and a basic PHP `foreach` question.

The first example you have is an Object, so you need to access the properties, e.g. meta_id, post_id like:

```
// THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE. YOUR VARIABLE WILL CHANGE BASED ON HOW YOU GOT THE DATA. `$object_array` is how you got the data to begin with.

foreach( $object_array as $object ) {
     $post_id = $object->post_id;
     echo $post_id;     
}
```

For your second example, since there is only one array key inside each array key, you would set it up like this:

```
// Example. you would use whatever you used to get the array to begin with as the `$array`.
foreach ($array as $item ) {
   $last_name = $item['last_name'][0];
   $first_name = $item['first_name'][0];
   ....
}
```